# jquery on click selector even listener not responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick

I am sure this will be easily spotted, but it is late here.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EightArmCode/qe8yd6j3/)

The desired outcome is that the user will have some feedback when they click on the active calendar links. You can tell the active ones, as the calendar numbers are darker, and they have an 'active' class on them.

Rendered markup:

```
<td class="active"><a href="#">23</a></td>
```

Right now, nothing happens when you click on any of the links. I feel like it must be my selector, but I'm not capturing it. There is already an event in the js (line 9), and I am just trying to trip the debugger to be sure I've triggered the event.

JS listener:

```
$('td.active').on('click', function(e) {
    debugger;
});
```

I've tried a number of selectors, and I can't seem to figure out the right syntax for this. I feel pretty certain it is just my selector, but I'm open to suggestion.

Please tell me what I'm missing. I could use some help. Thanks.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qe8yd6j3/1/

Comment: Worked like a charm, and great to read about delegated events. Cheers